# How to send inputs to a command using paramiko in python?

Tags: python, paramiko

There is a command, basically a `c` program, when executed on the remote machine. After executing that command it expects some inputs. Just like:

```
./sum
Enter two value: 8 9
sum is 17
```

How do I do this with `paramiko` after `ssh.exec_command("./sum")`? How to send the inputs 8 and 9 to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `stdin.write`

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('./sum')
stdin.write('8 9\n')
stdin.flush()
```